# Change default reminder times available in Gnome Calendar on Linux

Tags: linux, gnome, calendar, gnome-shell, reminder

Does anyone know how to change the default reminder times available in Gnome Calendar? The possible selections are:

- 5 minutes
- 10 minutes
- 30 minutes
- 1 hour
- 1 day
- 2 days
- 3 days
- 1 week

I'd like to add:

- 15 minutes
- 2 hours
- 2 weeks
- 4 weeks

Ben